# Regex for a allowing a certain file and excluding all others

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex to control multiple file types:

```
*\.(?:css|js|map|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$
```

But I would like to exclude  a particular config.js file from this regex. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What is your regex platform? If lookbehind is supported then use: `\.(?:css|js|map|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(?<!config\.js)$`. btw there is a redundant `*` at the start of your regex

Comment: why is * redundant at the beginning? The * is there to indicate that there can be any number of characters between the beginning of regex and dot character.

Comment: In regex that is `.*` not `*`

Comment: You're trying to exclude specific files based on their name, is that correct?

Comment: thanks for the clarification :). One more question, why have you includes .js in the second regex? The pattern to be excluded is .js having config before it.

Comment: @user1107888 it's important to let us know the regex engine/language you're using. The lookbehind may not be possible in your language, so a different method may be required. The *second regex* is part of the whole pattern - it's a negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes doesn't match `config.js`

Comment: @user1107888: Just placing `(?<!config)` before matching `\.` will skip `config.css` and config.map` etc also

Comment: @user1107888 Are you trying to filter files that match those extensions without the config files, or are you trying to get a list of the filenames via regex?

Comment: I am writing regex in the nginx.conf file, hope this helps regarding the regex engine

Comment: @anubhava, please add the regex you suggested as answer so that I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use a negative lookahead (instead of lookbehinds as lookbehinds are generally less supported (like Javascript supports lookaheads but doesn't support look behinds unless you're using Ecma script 2018 or higher)) if you exceptionally just want to disallow `config.js` name and hence using following regex,

```
^(?!config\.js$).*\.(?:css|js|map|eot|ttf|woff2?)$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CnjoHp/1)**

Here `^(?!config\.js$)` part will reject the match if the input is only and only exactly `config.js` where as it will allow for e.g. `myconfig.js` which I believe you may want to allow.

I have also shortened your `woff|woff2` to `woff2?` as both mean same and makes your regex a little more compact.

**Edit:**

As Anubhav pointed out, the `config.js` filename may be preceded by a directory name and in that case one can use following regex,

```
^(?!(.*[\\\/])?config\.js$).*\.(?:css|js|map|eot|ttf|woff2?)$
```

**[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/CnjoHp/2)**

Comment: This will only skip `config.js` if it is found at start. It won't skip `/file/config.js` for example.

Comment: @anubhava: Hey buddy, although OP didn't mention about directory names being present before the filename, but that can be easily taken care by optionally having a directory separator character. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since lookbehind is supported in `nginx.conf`, you may use this lookbehind assertion in your regex:

```
.*\.(?:css|js|map|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(?<!\bconfig\.js)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/49HsOZ/2)

`(?<!\bconfig\.js)` is negative lookbehind assertion to skip matching `config.js` while matching other `*.js`, `*.css` etc files. `\b` is for word boundary.

Comment: Hey Anubhav, great answer but your regex may also block something like `myconfig.js` in addition to mere `config.js` which OP might want to allow.

Comment: Thanks, this can be easily fixed by adding `\b` in lookbehind. See updated answer.

Comment: Hmmm... `\b` will still block names like `my-config.js` and any name where a non-word character is present before `config.js` filename. See my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59311330/11084116) which handles only `config.js` filename or a path having directory name before `config.js`